# My contact form doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, contacts

I have this contact form. When i press submit button it just reload the hole web page and doesn't send anything. It even doesn't show the success or error message. Please help me with that. 
There are my codes:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
  $('#contactform').on('submit',function(e) {

    $.ajax({
      url:'action.php',
      data:$(this).serialize(),
      type:'POST',
      success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $(".success").show().fadeOut(5000);
      },
      error:function(data){ $(".error").show().fadeOut(5000); }
      });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  
});

**<!-- This is php code: -->**

<?php

 $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
 $lastname   = $_POST['lastname'];
 $email     = $_POST['email'];
 $message    =   $_POST['message'];
 
 $to = 'kissa101295@gmail.com';
 $subject = 'Contact Form';
 $msg = "First Name: $firstname\nLast Name: $lastname\nEmail: $email\message: $message";
 mail($to, $firstname, $msg);

?>
```

```html
<form class="contactform" action="action.php" method="POST" name="contactform" id="contactform">

        <div class="errorwrap">
          <div class="error">Error!</div>
          <div class="success">Submitted!</div>
        </div>

        <div class="input-fields">
          <label>First Name: </label>
          <input class="text" type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" required />
        </div>

        <div class="input-fields">
          <label>Last Name: </label>
            <input class="text" type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" required />
        </div>

        <div class="input-fields">
          <label>Email: </label>
            <input class="text" type="text" name="email" id="email" required />
        </div>

        <div class="input-fields">
          <label> Message:</label>
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Write me a message here..."></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="buttons">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>

      </form>
```

Comment: start by reading the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: When you write a question about an error, __always__ include details of the error.Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: the page reload has nothing to do with php. Check browser console for script errors that are not allowing `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the reload

Comment: @Fred-ii- php manual won't help resolve client side issue with the form submitting by default process

Comment: @charlietfl that's why he said "*start* by"

Comment: @AlanMachado OP has identified a client side problem ... starting there makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is with header value in the function:

Try to add this header with this header parameters:

```
$headers = 'From: example@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: example@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $firstname, $message, $headers);
```

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: The $header parameter is optional though recommended.

Comment: doesn't account for the page reload